# Can't seem to get sample code to replace check boxes working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used code from the following:

[Fancy checkboxes](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/311/Fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-jquery)

The demo appears to work but it seems that it does not really change the status of the checkbox. Rather it just makes it looked checked or not checked.

Here's the HTML:

```
<fieldset class="checkboxes">
            <label for="checkbox-01" class="label_check c_on"><input type="checkbox" checked="" value="1" id="checkbox-01" name="sample-checkbox-01"> I agree to the terms &amp; conditions.</label>
            <label for="checkbox-02" class="label_check"><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox-02" name="sample-checkbox-02"> Please send me regular updates.</label>
        </fieldset>
```

Here's the javascript that is used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setupLabel() {
        if ($('.label_check input').length) {
            $('.label_check').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('c_on');
            });
            $('.label_check input:checked').each(function () {
                $(this).parent('label').addClass('c_on');
            });
        };
    };
    var linkObj;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.label_check, .label_radio').click(function () {
            setupLabel();
        });
        setupLabel();
```

Can someone please confirm if there's a problem with the code. Seems to me that the author has missed making the code change the checkbox checked state.

Here's the code I use to check the status of the checkbox:

```
var action = $('#htmlEdit').is(":checked") ? "Editing HTML" : "Editing";
```

Am I doing the check wrongly or is the author's code just not changing the input element?

Comment: what do you mean by status of the checkbox?

Comment: I mean the value of the input element that is associated with the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Not clear, but it works

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/U4cLN/

When you click a label that uses
`<label for="checkboxID" />`,  the box gets checked (and unchecked) in any browser without needing JavaScript. It is pure browser default behaviour

So

`<LABEL class="label_check" for="checkbox-02"><INPUT name="sample-checkbox-02" id="checkbox-02" value="1" type="checkbox"> Please send me regular updates.</LABEL>`

will check the box and the script styles the label

Comment: The box gets checked but it seems to me the input element doesn't change: <input id="checkbox-01" type="checkbox" checked="" value="1" name="sample-checkbox-01">

Comment: Seems to you how? You will not see any change if you view source. Look at my fiddle and click the button at the bottom to test the second checkbox

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear. I was using firebug and watching in the firebug HTML window. I saw the classes change but the input element code all stayed the same. Tried the same on your fiddle. I'm confused as I expected to see the input element change to show checked. Also what is it in the jscript that makes it change? I just see class changes.

Comment: Nothing in the JavaScript changes the checked state. It is pure html. Click a label that has for=id will check the box in any browser without javascript.